# Overloading [ ] operator for stl map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
class foo{

public:
    int a, b, c;
    double val;

    foo(int a){
        ...
    }

...
}
```

Now I want to do:

```
map <foo*, double> mymap;

foo fa(2);
foo fb(4);

mymap[fa] = 1.0;
mymap[fb] = 2.0;
```

Obviously I get the error that [ ] is undefined for type foo. But how do I overload this operator? And for that matter, how do I get a pointer to foo? Because I'm assuming it's not defined since foo is a custom class

Comment: "How do I get a pointer" should be part of your C++ textbook or course material. "Why do I want a pointer" is an entirely different question :-)

Answer (score 3):

The key has to be of type `foo*`. So you need to write this:

```
mymap[&fa] = 1.0;
mymap[&fb] = 2.0;
```

But remember that **if** `fa` and `fb` are local objects, then they will be destroyed when you return from the function. So you should not return `mymap` from the function, as the objects used as keys don't exist once the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to oveload anything here. Your map expects pointers to `foo`, so you need to pass pointers to `foo`. You can fix your code like this:

```
mymap[&fa] = 1.0;
mymap[&fb] = 2.0;
```

**Beware** you have to be absolutely sure that the `foo` objects will live as long as or longer than the map, otherwise the latter would end up with dangling pointers. This, for example, would end in tears:

```
map <foo*, double> mymap;

{
  foo fa(2);
  foo fb(4);
  mymap[&fa] = 1.0;
  mymap[&fb] = 2.0;
} // fa and fb cease to exist

// state of mymap is messed up here.
```

Comment: Yet, inserting pointers to local objects through the reference operator is usually a very bad idea. Btw, I know the map is on the same scope of the objects so it shouldn't be a problem but if the usage changes it really needs to be considered

Comment: @emartel The map and the `foos` are in the same scope so it is reasonably safe.

Comment: yes that's why I edited my comment to point out I was aware of this, but if the OP didn't realize, it's important for him to know

Answer (score 0):

Keeping and using pointer to some local objects inside a map may be **extemely** dangerous. First of all you may crash your app by dereferencing `std::map` key when the objects go out of scope. Moreover it is really hard to use and in most cases not what programmer inteded. In your case:

```
auto it = mymap.find(&foo(2))
```

will not compile and:

```
foo fc(2);
auto it = mymap.find(&fc);
```

will not find any value inside the container (`fa` have the same value but different pointer). Is it really what you wanted?

It is why I would recommend redefining your `std::map` to `std::map<foo, double> mymap;` which will keep and compare `foo` by value. To make it work you will need to either implement `foo::operator<()` or provide your own soring algorithm to `std::map` as template argument. First case will look like that:

```
class foo {
  int a, b, c;
  double val;
public:
  foo(int a) {}
  bool operator<(const foo &other) const
  { return a < other.a && b < other.b && c < other.c; }
};


int main()
{
  std::map<foo, double> mymap;

  foo fa(2);
  foo fb(4);

  mymap[fa] = 1.0;
  mymap[fb] = 2.0;

  auto it = mymap.find(foo(2));
}
```